# Android, how to merge two custom ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

So, I have two different ArrayList with custom object. First one is ArrayList which cointain date like "Today", "Tomorrow" etc, second one is ArrayList which cointains information about events. I want to send them to RecyclerAdapter, and then with two holders make recycler view of items. Something like that:

- Today

  - Event I
  - Event II
  - Event III
- Tomorrow

  - Event IV
  - Event V

I would like to merge this ArrayLists in one and then send them to adapter, but i have no clue, how can I achieve that

Comment: You want to just merge the arrays one after another or you want to have final list sorted?

Comment: Did you look at the link?

Comment: Yup, i resolve my problem, thanks to you ;)

Comment: Happy for you! and what particularly helped you? this algorithm? or other method?

Comment: Your link was very helpfull, and mainly I resolve my problem with your advice

Comment: If so, please up vote or accept my answer. I would appreciate that

Comment: I will do taht, but at start i need to get 15 reputation :/

Comment: You can also accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically data structure question. You can use Merge Sort algorithm. There are many tutorial on web. Link for one of them is given below. Run through it and you will have an idea of how to solve your problem.

http://howtodoinjava.com/algorithm/merge-sort-java-example/

It is basically theory. You will probably need to think on your own algorithm.